# Query to join 2 columns of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table txn(id,orig_num,rec_num)

How to write a query to return distinct values present in both column? I want to join these two columns (orig_num and rec_num) and return 1 column (say acct_num) which will have distinct account numbers. I am using sql server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select orig_num as acct_num from your_table
union
select rec_num from your_table
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b358/1)

Comment: @juergend Thank you so much. One day, I will learn to think like and write queries like you.